# Navigation Broken: The menu link "Home" points to a nonexistent ID "#home" - javascript prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3

Ever since I played around (meaning enabled it in production) with asset.precompiling, I have started seeing funky functionality locally.

Specifically, I started seeing this pop-up when the page is just loaded.

```
Navigation Broken: The menu link "Home" points to a nonexistent ID "#home". 
To solve this, add the ID "home" to a tag, for example: <article id="home">
```

[image: Pop-up]

Once I click through the pop-up, the links work fine.

This is a single page site, so when I click on a menu item it scrolls down properly.

This is how the `nav` looks:

```
<nav class="menu two-thirds column omega">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a><br /></li>
                <li><a href="#features" class="active">What is it?</a><br /></li>
                <li><a href="#pricing" class="active">How much?</a><br /></li>
                <li><a href="/login" class="active">Login</a><br /></li>                
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

The actual element looks like this:

```
<article id="features" class="dark">
```

Thoughts?

Comment: can you post a link or share a jsfiddle? this looks like some background js is being fired

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I wish I could, but I wouldn't know what to put in the jsfiddle. As fate would have it, the public version of this particular page is not producing this error (I only see it locally) - but I suspect it may be causing other errors on the public one that I am trying to track down. I checked the JS console and I am not seein g anything. What can I try to get more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix I found is just changing the paths to the anchor tags from `#home` to `\#home`.

Not sure what causes this issue, but that fixed it for me.